# Request error "enable cookies" while posting app request to LinkedIn

Tags: java-me, oauth, linkedin-api, s60

I am running S60 SDK 5th with Eclipse pulsar on win 7.

I have oauth_token using with this Url https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=. To get that grant access screen by LinkedIn.

I am loading above Url using htmlComponent, and adding HtmlComponent to form and show it.
Occasionally when I click on the "Ok I'll Allow It" button (i.e. after the button has been pressed) I get the following error message.

> We’re sorry, there was a problem with your request. Please make sure you have cookies enabled and try again.

But I'm receiving the response with oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, oauth_callback_confirmed = true, xoauth_request_auth_url, oauth_expires_in.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the error is happening with the callback.  Once you click the "OK, I'll allow it" button in the LinkedIn authentication page, the user should be redirected back to your application.  Can you run the network for your phone through a laptop system where you can snoop the traffic to see what's happening?  I'm not familiar with HTTP snooping capabilities in the Windows 7 system, but there may be some logging you can do to determine what's happening.

Comment: no actually i found that i think because i'm passing wrong params to submit url of LinkedIn. i.e. [Link](https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize/submit?extra=&access=-3&duration=0&csrfToken=ajax%3A1363873184829698131&sourceAlias=0_8L1usXMS_e_-SfuxXa1idxJ207ESR8hAXKfus4aDeAk&oauth_token=367064f6-63fe-4c86-90b2-Z20c523be3ad&session_password=jay8928928363&session_key=jayeshkvarma%40gmail.com&appId=&agree=true&authorize=Ok%2C%20I%27ll%20Allow%20It)

This url is gives that error.
i'm now trying to find right set of params to supply to submit url.

Comment: Your link has all sorts of parameters that aren't expected or allowed in OAuth.  You don't send the username and password, or any other similar things.  You need to either use an existing OAuth library or carefully read the Authentication section on the LinkedIn developer site to understand how the authentication system works.

Comment: In what unit is 599 in oauth_expires_in? 
is it seconds? or minutes?